# How to save the query results of CPLEX solver?

Tags: c++, cplex

I am using CPLEX concert technology (with C++) to solve a linear program several times in a loop. At each iteration, I want to save the output of `cplex.getCplexStatus()` into a vector so I could print it into a file later. I first introduced a vector using `vector <string> LP_STATUS;` and then tried to capture the output by using `LP_STATUS.push_back (cplex.getCplexStatus() ) ;` in the loop. However, I end up with the following error:

> severity: 'Error' message: 'no instance of overloaded function
>   "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Tp=std::__cxx11::string,
>   _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (IloCplex::CplexStatus) -- object type is:
>   std::vector>' at: '132,13' source: '' code:
>   'undefined'

Could you please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a compiler error because the [getCplexStatus](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex.html#method_getCplexStatus) method returns a value from the [IloCplex::CplexStatus](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/enumerations/IloCplex_CplexStatus.html) enumeration *not* a string. One way to fix this is, like so:

```
vector<IloCplex::CplexStatus> LP_STATUS;
LP_STATUS.push_back (cplex.getCplexStatus());
```

That is, we declare `LP_STATUS` as a vector of `IloCplex::CplexStatus` rather than a vector of `string`.

Comment: Thanks rkersh. I just have two more questions. Can I print the contents of `LP_STATUS` directly, e.g., by using `fprintf (myfile, "%s " , LP_STATUS[0] )`? I am asking this because the content of our vector is not a string. In addition, in my code I have the vector `vector <float> LP_OBJVAL`.

I can write `LP_OBJVAL.push_back( cplex.getObjValue() )` without any errors. Why don't I face with an error while `cplex.getObjValue()` does not return a `float`?

Comment: For your first question, the answer is no (as an exercise, you should try it and see what the compiler tells you). Rather than the `"%s"` format string you'd need to use `"%d"` instead. For your second question, the compiler doesn't stop you from doing bad things. There might be a legitimate reason to cast from a double to a float, but you can run into underflow and overflow issues, as well as loss of precision. You should really declare `LP_OBJVAL` as a vector of doubles. You should search the internet for "cast double to float" to find more information about this.

Comment: I also suggest that you read about the [best way to ask follow up questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767).